# Logistic curve fitting with nls2

Tags: r

I am using the nls2 R package to fit logistic curves to many datasets. The data is detection probability of a signal at multiple distances. There is a noise source around 600 m that causes the probability to drop to 0.

An example dataset:

```
Distance    DetectionProb
0   61.11111111
100 88.88888889
150 72.22222222
200 72.22222222
250 38.88888889
300 38.88888889
350 61.11111111
400 72.22222222
450 33.33333333
500 0
550 0
600 0
650 0
700 0
750 38.88888889
800 55.55555556
850 72.22222222
900 33.33333333
950 77.77777778
1000    72.22222222
1050    83.33333333
1100    0
1150    0
```

The model I'm using (R version 99.887, Windows 10):

```
model=nls2(DetectionProb~theta1/(1+exp(-(theta2-theta3*Distance))),data=trial, start = list(theta1=100,theta2=7,theta3=0.02), algorithm="port",trace=TRUE, lower=list(theta1=0,theta2=0,theta3=0),upper=list(theta1=100,theta2=100,theta3=100))
summary(model)
deltaMethod(model,"theta2/theta3")
```

This returns an estimate of 450.4957 with a SE of 1322.007.
Is the standard error so large because the data is noisy?

I would appreciate any advice you may have about whether this is the correct way to go about fitting a logistic curve to this dataset.

Thank you.

Comment: I would use a self-starting model (see `help("SSlogis")`)  with `nls`. However, your data clearly doesn't follow a logistic curve. You are using the wrong model.

Comment: Look at the `drm` function in the `drc` package.

Comment: Also remove the rows with zero values.